# Is Bramacharya necessary for spiritual advancement?

Tags: scripture, vedas, bhagavad-gita, bhakti, manuscripts

Is there any scriptural representation showing that **Bramacharya** is necessary for spiritual advancement ? How is Bramacharya helpful?

Answer (score 3):

There are scriptural verses that say Brahmacharya is necessary for spiritual advancement.

> Abstinence from sexual acts, neither brooding nor imagining about it
> and complete sexual detachment is called celibacy (Brahmacharya).

**Vayu Purana I.59.46**

> **Celibacy**, Japa, silence and fasting – these are the roots of penance. Penance is hard and very difficult of achievement.

**Vayu Purana I.59.41**

Brahmacharya helps by powering the spiritual aspirant with tremendous energy and gigantic will-power.

> By the establishment of continence energy is gained.

**Patanjali Yoga II.38**

> The chaste brain has tremendous energy and gigantic will power.
> Without chastity there can be no spiritual strength. Continence gives
> wonderful control over mankind. The spiritual leaders of men have
> been very continent, and this is what gave them power. Therefore the
> Yogi must be continent.

Commentary in Raja Yoga by Swami Vivekananda

Answer (score 2):

*Brahmacharya is imperative for a successful dhyana*

> **prashantatma vigata-bhir brahmachari-vrate sthitah
> manah sanyamya mach-chitto yukta asita mat-parah**
> Thus, with a serene, fearless, and unwavering mind, and staunch in the vow of celibacy, the vigilant yogi should meditate on Me, having Me alone as the supreme goal.
> (Bhagavad Gita 6.14 Translation Swami Mukundananda)

---

*“Without purifying the body through austerity, one cannot reach the final state of yog.” Rig veda 9.83.1*

> **deva-dwija-guru-prājña- pūjanaṁ śhaucham ārjavam
> brahmacharyam ahinsā cha śhārīraṁ tapa uchyate**
> When worship of the Supreme Lord, the Brahmins, the spiritual master, the wise, and the elders is done with the observance of cleanliness, simplicity, celibacy, and non-violence then this worship is declared as the austerity of the body.
> (Bhagavad Gita 17.14)

Swami Mukundananda

---

> **..yad ichchhanto brahmacharyam charanti tat te padam sangrahena pravakshye**
> .. great ascetics practice the vow of celibacy and renounce worldly pleasures to enter into Him. I shall now explain to you briefly the path to that goal.
> (Bhagavad Gita 8.11 Translation Swami Mukundananda)

---

Sarva Vedanta Sidhanta Sara Sangraha (109/110) by Sri Shankaracharya -

Celibacy is attained by, not longing to become a captive, by means of , eight fold fetters

> स्त्रीणाम् स्मरणम् दर्शनम् गुण-कर्मानुकीर्तनम् तासु समीचीनत्व-धीः प्रीतिः मिथः सम्भाषणम्…सह-वासः च संसर्गः (एवम्) अष्टधा मैथुनम् विदुः एतद्-विलक्षणम् ब्रह्म-चर्यम् चित्त-प्रसादकम् (अस्ति)।

1. thinking of women.2. seeing them,3. praising their qualities and deeds. 4. fancing them as beautiful, 5. loves them 6. talks to them in private. 7.dwelling together, 8.close companionship  with them. But it is only by shunning all this that Brahmacharya may be attained. It is only by this means that it is possible to attain serenity of mind.

---

Following verses  are from
sanatsujAtIyam , in the mahAbhArata on
(chapters 41 to 46 of
udyogaparva. It consists of four chapters with a total of 146 verses - Courtesy Sri SN Sastri).

> **AdyAm vidyAm vadasi hi satyarUpAm
> yA prApyate brahmacaryeNa sadbhih |
> yAm prApyainam martyabhAvam tyajanti
> yA vai vidyAguruvRdheshu nityA** ||3 
> You are asking about the knowledge of that uncaused Truth which is beyond this unreal universe. It can be attained only by the wise who
> practise brahmacarya. On attaining that one sheds the notion of being a mere mortal. This knowledge reposes in one to whom it has been
> imparted by his guru.

> **sanatsujAta said—
> naitad brahma tvaramANena labhyam
> yanmAm pRcchasyabhishangeNa rAjan |
> buddhau praline manasi pracintyA
> vidyA hi sA brahmacaryeNa labhyA** ||2 
> O king, this brahman about which you are asking me with such
> eagerness cannot be attained by a person who is in a hurry. This
> knowledge is to be meditated upon by the intellect in which the mind has merged, i.e., when the cogitating mind has been withdrawn from all external objects and has become fixed on the Self. This knowledge which
> is to be meditated upon can be attained only by the practice of
> ‘brahmacarya’

Comment: Sir, as it says as, **the one who praises their qualities & deeds & the one who is in close companionship**. For eg, in School or University, most teachers are females & thus praised for their teaching by students. Also, it is unevitable to avoid female classmates as, indeed close acquaintance do occur with them over time. Thus what is your stand on this?

Comment: @Chamundadas, If seen in Letter and Spirit, it is the bhava /attitude that matters, which is internal to oneself. Swami Vivekananda (wasn't inimical towards women) , but His bhava to see every woman as His mother, explains what celibacy is . I've quoted Sri Shankaras words verbatim. This is my view of it.

Comment: Sir, thanks to explain. Got that.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks